# SciKit learn, modifying make_moons and getting: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to modify the default make_moons dataset, which i believe is just an array of integers.

I am getting the error:

```
C:\Users\Thomas\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/!UFV/CIS480/project/SKLTest-testingForArray.py
C:\Users\Thomas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
C:\Users\Thomas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\lda.py:6: DeprecationWarning: lda.LDA has been moved to discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis in 0.17 and will be removed in 0.19
  "in 0.17 and will be removed in 0.19", DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/!UFV/CIS480/project/SKLTest-testingForArray.py", line 208, in <module>
    for name, (X, y) in [('moon', newer_make_moons(noise=0.3, random_state=0)),
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the array 'newer_make_moons':

```
newer_make_moons = (np.array(
              [
                 [1,2],
                 [3,4],
                 [5,6]
              ]),
       np.array(
           [(
              [
                 1,
                 0,
                 0
              ])
           ], dtype=int))
```

Here is where the array is used, and where the error is occuring:

```
for name, (X, y) in [('moon', newer_make_moons(noise=0.3, random_state=0)),
                    ('circles', make_circles(noise=0.2, factor=0.5, random_state=1)),
                    ('linear', linearly_separable)]:
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.4, random_state=1)
    # standardize data
    scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
    datasets[name] = {'X_train': scaler.transform(X_train), 'y_train': y_train,
                      'X_test': scaler.transform(X_test), 'y_test': y_test}

est = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
# plots the datasets - see Appendix
plot_datasets(est)
```

Comment: `newer_make_moons` is not a function, its a tuple of numpy array. You are trying to make a function call to it.

Comment: Why do you want to edit the `make_moons` and what do you want to modify in there? Here's [the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/datasets/samples_generator.py#L639).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to call the `make_moons` function. Replace `newer_make_moons` to `make_moons` in

```
for name, (X, y) in [('moon', newer_make_moons(noise=0.3, random_state=0)), ('circles', make_circles(noise=0.2, factor=0.5, random_state=1)), ('linear', linearly_separable)]:
```

Comment: Your right, I should be calling a function instead. But I want to call a modified version of make_moons, and can't find where make_moons is to edit it. Is it online and I am not able to edit it? Or is it on my computer somewhere? I imported with: `from sklearn.datasets import make_moons, make_circles, make_classification`

Comment: For that you would need to write a function and call it `newer_make_moons` and implement a modified version of the default `make_moons` function in it.

Comment: Am I able to get the source code for make_moons? Because I don't know how to write it from scratch, and if I don't have the source code i don't know how i could implement a modified version of the default make_moons.

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/202b5321f1798c4980abf69ac8c0a0969f01a2ec/sklearn/datasets/samples_generator.py#L639

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that you're trying to call `newer_make_moons` as a function, but it's actually a tuple. If you remove all of the data, the format of `newer_make_moons` is a tuple with two `np.array()` objects inside. Those arrays also don't have the ability to be called as functions.

Additionally, `newer_make_moons` is a bit messy. You don't need all of those brackets in the second one. This is all you need:

```
newer_make_moons = (
  np.array([
    [1,2],
    [3,4],
    [5,6]
  ]),
  np.array([1, 0, 0], dtype=int)
)
```

Comment: you're right, make_moons which was originally called was a function. Do you know how i could modify make_moons and call that version? I cannot find make_moons.

Comment: Where's the source code? I don't have any familiarity with the library you're using and your post doesn't contain any links.